# C#: Drawing Stripes using the GDI/+ Libraries

Tags: c#, drawing

I would like to know if there is a way to take create a brush that paints stripes in C#; I'm using the 4.0 standard.

For simplicity, two colors, and possibly an angle.

Any references or websites would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing at Windows Forms: HatchBrush is probably your best bet.  TextureBrush is the most flexible.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a good hatch brush demo: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/HatchBrushStyles.htm, still looking into texture brush.

Comment: TextureBrush demo: http://www.deitel.com/articles/csharp_tutorials/20051025/IntroTo2DGraphics.html